# Group secret agreement for clients do not have connection to each other

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

In my idea, $n$ clients will have the connection to a server, and clients will not be able to connect with other clients. Are there any previous design has been published to let $n$ clients agree on a same shared secret, while the server does not know what the secret is?

Comment: What is the trust level of the clients and server; honest, semi-honest, covert, malicious?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. The problem is that setting up such a system can be done in many ways, even server-less. In general I'd say that having a shared secret should **not** be the goal. You'd rather have channel or message specific keys. Hence my recommendation to study other protocols. In general, data encryption is relatively simple, transfer protocols are harder and multi-party communication protocols are even harder than that. You're starting at the top.

Comment: @kelalaka I think I will start with honest-but-curious first.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, sure, I will think again about the requirements.

Comment: Pretty much any system designed for a peer-to-peer network also works if the connections go through a central server - think about it: the P2P network still works if all peers are connected to the same ISP router. But you can't rely on the server to help the clients recognize each other, because it could lie. The clients would (probably) all have to know who the other clients are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-party or group Diffie-Hellman algorithms effectively facilitate the generation of a shared secret among multiple parties. However, they inherently lack mechanisms for participant authentication **if** ephemeral key pairs are used.

If no authentication is performed then unauthorized entities may join the secure group, potentially leading to the compromise of group communications. Additionally, the security of the entire group is contingent on the integrity of individual private keys; the exposure of even a single private key renders the entire group's security vulnerable.

What is required is both secure key exchange and participant authentication. The Signal protocol is one such example that offers robust security features, including forward secrecy and end-to-end encryption. Another protocol of interest could be the Group Secure Association Key Management Protocol (GSAKMP), which specifically addresses the complexities of secure key management in group communications.

Comment: Note that I have not personally studied GSAKMP for some reason or other. Also note that I used ChatGPT to *formalize* (not generate) my answer (this due to my brain being not fully up to speed after my kayaking holiday).

Comment: As far as I know, Diffie-Hellman requires a direct connection between party, which is not existing in my current setup. To sum up, in my current setup, only the clients can only communicate with the server. I have a little look at the Signal's protocol and I do not feel like it shares the properties with my setup? Can you please re-verify about this?

Comment: @AnhNguyễnTuấn "requires a direct connection", not necessarily. They just have to be able to reach each other, and through a server (implementing some cross-communication protocol) is one such possibility. The contents and medium of communication are separate concepts.